# ServiceLoader not loading new services

Tags: java, maven, module, serviceloader

My ServiceLoader dont want to load my new service. I think I have everything correctly setted up.

Core.Main

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Before");
      Iterator<IService> services = ServiceLoader.load(IService.class).iterator();
      while (services.hasNext()) {
          IService service = services.next();
          System.out.println(service.sayHi());
      }
      System.out.println("After");
  }
}
```

Core.service.IService

```
package service;

public interface IService {
    String sayHi();
}
```

DbDataBuilder.builder.DbDataBuilder

```
package builder;

import service.IService;
public class DbDataBuilder implements IService {

    public DbDataBuilder() {
    }

    public String sayHi() {
        return "I am Data Builder";
    }
 }
```

META-INF/services/service.Iservice

```
builder.DbDataBuilder
```

[image: Project structure]

But when I run it, console output is:

```
Before
After
```

Do I something wrong?

Comment: Does it work when calling the service directly? If not you probably have a classpath problem.

Comment: I dont know how to do it, cause DbDataBuilder needs dependency to Core (Iservice interface) and if I want to call DbDataBuilder from Core, I would need DBDataBuilder dependency in it, but its a cyclic dependency and it dont want to compile. So Im not able to call it directly.

Comment: Did you try with a simple implementation as the one you posted? Note that such cyclic dependencies are not that much of a problem if you compile the classes in one go. It might be that the service loader just doesn't see the service hence the test with a direct call.

Comment: Add to Main.java the following line: `Class.forName("builder.DbDataBuilder")` I expect you will get ClassNotFoundException and it will be a proof that builder is not visible on classpath, so cannot be found by ServiceLoader

Comment: Yes, it throws ClassNotFoundException. How can I fix it?

Comment: But if I got DbDataBuilder in classpath, then ServiceLoader doesnt make sense, right?

Comment: ServiceLoader is useful when builder is on classpath at runtime, not at compile time. You should add third module with compile scope dependency to `Core` and runtime scope dependency to `DbDataBuilder`, move `Main` to the third module and enjoy ServiceLoader features

Comment: It works. Thank you very much!

Comment: @michaldo You help me too. You should get this comment as a answer so you could get you proper upvotes! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

ServiceLoader is useful when builder is on classpath at runtime, not at compile time. You should add third module with compile scope dependency to Core and runtime scope dependency to DbDataBuilder, move Main to the third module and enjoy ServiceLoader features